# No "ping notices" in my inbox today!

Tags: bug, notifications

It looks like the "user ping notices" in the comments are not showing up in my inbox today.

For example is Pieter Goosen using @birgire in two comments today: [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186198/get-y-random-authors-id-object-with-more-than-x-number-of-posts#comment271856_186198) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186198/get-y-random-authors-id-object-with-more-than-x-number-of-posts/186220#comment271869_186220), but there are no notices showing up in my inbox:

[image: My inbox queue]

Did this also stop working for you today?

### Update:

It looks like the reason I didn't get those ping notices is because they are "cold" and they are not collected for the inbox.

See for example: [Does the @ reply in comments work cold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67131/does-the-reply-in-comments-work-cold)

Always learning something new everyday ;-)

Comment: It would be nice if we can get notified whenever we are noted in comments. Specially in the cases you've mentioned as it involves previous answers and answers that is linked to that specific user. :-) I just wonder though about the abuse factor of such an implementation. One might gt pinged unnecessarily for something quite irrelevant

Comment: yes, I wasn't aware of these restriction, but I can imagine the large amount of "inbox spam" in the worst case scenarios ;-) @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for notifications are [pretty elaborate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/163749). From quick look at the thread it's likely you hadn't been notified since system doesn't consider you as participant in it.

Comment: Many thanks for the link, it looks like the pings in my question are "cold" ;-)